# Date format using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get the formatted date from data result?

```
var obj = data.map(row => ({
     id: row[0],
     status: row[1],
     datepublished: row[2]
}));
```

This is the result when i didnt format the `datepublished` field

```
[
    {
        "id": 440937003,
        "status": "Not Available",
        "datepublished": "2022-03-27T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
]

var obj = data.map(row => ({
     id: row[0],
     status: row[1],
     datepublished: new Date(row[2].getTime() - (row[2].getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 )).toISOString().split("T")
}));
```

This is my current result data

```
[
    {
        "id": 440937003,
        "status": "Not Available",
        "datepublished": [
            "2022-03-28",
            "00:00:00.000Z"
        ]
    },
]
```

what I want result is

```
[
    {
        "id": 440937003,
        "status": "Not Available",
        "datepublished": "2022-03-28"
    },
]
```

Comment: Use `[0]` after `.split("T")` to get the first element of the array.

Comment: I've tried but the result is `null`

Comment: Why do you subtract timezone  offset? Be careful with that. It hardly ever does what you need.

Comment: I've just copy one of the answer on how to format a date

Comment: `datepublished: new Date(row[2].getTime() - (row[2].getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 )).toISOString().split("T")[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 440937003,
    status: 'Not Available',
    datepublished: '2022-03-27T16:00:00.000Z',
  },
];

const parsedData = data.map(({ id, status, datepublished }) => ({
  id,
  status,
  datepublished: datepublished.slice(0, 10),
}));

console.log(parsedData)
```

Comment: should i declare the `datepublished`?

Comment: What is the point of parsing the date and then outputting as ISO string again?

Comment: You can make it optional by conditional statement (if i understand your question) @kaito

Comment: Why not just do `datepublished: datepublished.slice(0,10)`? or use `substring(0,10)` instead?

Comment: @phuzi I create an editable date by using `new Date(string representating a date)` and changing as a specific format (ISO string here) and remove the useless part (hours, minutes, seconds) by using a `slice` method

Comment: @phuzi, you can't slice a `Date()`

Comment: @phuzi oh my bad, I've dont realized that already is a ISO string

Answer (score 0):

Your [ISO 8601 string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is in UTC as the [`Z` indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) so `split()[0]` or `substring(0, 10)` are the best option if you need UTC.

In case you need your string in another timezone parse it first and then use [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with locale of `en-CA` (this will print `year-month-day`) and whatever timezone you need as an option like this:

```js
// For UTC
const iso8601str = "2022-03-27T16:00:00.000Z";
const split = iso8601str.split("T")[0];
const substring = iso8601str.substring(0, 10);

// For another timezone
// parse first, then format in desired timezone
// locale "en-CA" ensures format of year-month-day
const asiaDateStr = new Date(iso8601str).toLocaleDateString(
  "en-CA",
  { timeZone: "Asia/Shanghai" } // options objects which also takes timeZone as an argument
);
console.log("In UTC wiht split():", split);
console.log("In UTC with substring():", substring);
console.log("In Asia/Shanghai:", asiaDateStr);
```

Have a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) to see what options exist for `timeZone`.